# Asset caching with Webpack 5 loaders

Tags: webpack, caching, webpack-5

I'm currently trying to use caching with Webpack 5 loaders, in order not to compile every single asset in my project every time I build for production, since they're basically never changing.
I tried adding filesystem Webpack caching but the issue is that we use a single entry bundle, which imports everything at some point.
I saw `cache-loader` for Webpack 4 which seems to do exactly what I want but I'd like to know if there's a better solution - and if possible native.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you either have to watch every file and rebuild the bundle on every change, or split it into several bundles.

However, import everything shouldn't matter much, see https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#caching :

> In watch mode, only modified files are evicted from the cache. If watch mode is off, then the cache gets purged before every compilation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately we can't use watch mode for production builds.
The problem was about production bundles, I probably should've specified that. I'd like to use a cache for the webpack build, not the watch environment, as this one loads everything dynamically using the dev server.

Comment: Hmm, we build everything clean to avoid caching issues.

However, I've just tested this.

Clean build:
`npx webpack --mode=production
Build completed in 17.589s`

Cached build (no changes):
`npx webpack --mode=production
Build completed in 1.427s`

Cached build (changed a file):
`npx webpack --mode=production
Build completed in 4.368s`. In this case, you might want to bring the previous cache from `node_modules/.cache/webpack` to your production build systems.